# Removing dead players from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have this REST API for a game where you can join the multiplayer and automatically get assigned to a lobby and play with people all around the world.

when player connects to multiplayer, they send a request to the API `/connectToGame` with an authorization token in header

**1.** i take their sessionId from the bearer token (the token is given by another route to the player) and first i find an available lobby with empty player slot and i push their sessionId to that lobby's sessions array (let's their sid is `1002783919`)

after this, the lobby looks like this:

```json
{
  "_id": "63495c6ff4de52ec18eb4978",
  "lobbyId": "e3504041-5eb6-4036-a23a-14ff815c1d45",
  "sessions": [
    1002783919
  ],
}
```

**2.** i create a session object for the player with their sid and player information and assign the lobbyId from their joined lobby to the player object

```json
{
  "_id": "63495e81e2aab91b8d2f9823",
  "sessionId": 1002783919,
  "lobbyId": "e3504041-5eb6-4036-a23a-14ff815c1d45",
  "player": {
    "avatar": 372,
    "name": "TEST",
    "onlinescore": 1,
    "country": 8519
  },
  "updatedAt": "2022-10-14T12:56:15.373+00:00"
}
```

every 5 seconds the game pings the server and i update the player's session `updatedAt` to `Date.now()` so i know that session is still alive and is being used.

there is no problem until here, i just wanted to show you guys the process

if player wants to leave multiplayer, the game does POST `/leaveGame` with their sessionid in body. when it happens, i just take their sid, remove the sid from lobby and delete their session entry

but sometimes, players might just unexpectedly close their game and it wont leave any chance for the game to do that leaveGame request. therefore the session entry and the sid in lobby will always stay in the db forever.

i was thinking of a way of how i can remove dead players entry and their lobby sid from the db and someone told me to use node cron and check every 30 seconds for dead players and remove them. you can tell if a session is not alive if their `updatedAt` hasn't been updated in 1 minute (because player pings server every 5 seconds). do you guys think it's an efficient way or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to add TTL index on field updatedAt and set some time that you want, like 1 minute, so that if updatedAt value is older than current time - 1 minute, mongo will delete it automatically.

Docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/

Comment: right, i've tried this before on session objects, works fine but how am i supposed to detect those documents who get deleted by ttl and remove them from their lobby? otherwise their sid will stay in a lobby's array while the session actually doesnt exist